# R: SentimentAnalysis Package

Tags: r, grouping, sentiment-analysis

Does anyone know why `aggregate` argument in function `analyzeSentiment` from [SentimentAnalysis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SentimentAnalysis/index.html) package in R is not grouping sentiment scores? Here is a simple reproducable example:

```
> library(SentimentAnalysis)
> documents <- c("Wow, I really like the new light sabers!",
+                "That book was excellent.",
+                "R is a fantastic language.",
+                "The service in this restaurant was miserable.",
+                "This is neither positive or negative.",
+                "The waiter forget about my dessert -- what poor service!")
> Group=factor(c(1,1,2,2,3,3))
> Test_data=data.frame(documents=documents,Group=Group,stringsAsFactors = F)
> sentiment <- analyzeSentiment(x=Test_data$documents,aggregate=Test_data$Group)
> Test_data$SentimentQDAP=sentiment$SentimentQDAP
> Test_data
                                                 documents Group SentimentQDAP
1                 Wow, I really like the new light sabers!     1     0.3333333
2                                 That book was excellent.     1     0.5000000
3                               R is a fantastic language.     2     0.5000000
4            The service in this restaurant was miserable.     2    -0.3333333
5                    This is neither positive or negative.     3     0.0000000
6 The waiter forget about my dessert -- what poor service!     3    -0.4000000
```

Which gives me the following:

[image]

The help on function analyzeSentiment  says that " **aggregate**: A factor variable by which documents can be grouped. This helpful when joining e.g. news from the same day or move reviews by the same author".

The question I have is that why scores are not the same within each group?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the [source code](https://rdrr.io/cran/SentimentAnalysis/src/R/analyzeSentiment.R) of the `analyzeSentiment` function to see what happens with that `aggregate` argument.

Interestingly, the reason it's not doing anything within your code is because that argument is *essentially redundant* - it never gets used at all! If you follow the call stack starting from the initial `analyzeSentiment` function, the `aggregate` argument just gets passed around until it reaches the main hub of sentiment computation - the `analyzeSentiment.DocumentTermMatrix`. This is where the data frame of results is computed and then returned, and the value passed to `aggregate` seems to make no appearance anywhere in the code. It's passed in and never used.

Must be either a feature they never added to the package, or an artifact left over from a previous version for the sake of backward compatibility.